# Unable to get the base address of kernel level process

Tags: python

I'm trying to attach my Python program to this kernel level exe called `"ntoskrnl.exe"` and write to its memory.

However I'm unable to attach my program to `"ntoskrnl.exe"` via pymem or readwritememory and was wondering if someone could help me attach my program to `"ntoskrnl.exe"` and get its base address and write to it's memory.

I've so far tried pymem:

```
pm = pymem.Pymem("ntoskrnl.exe")
base = pm.base_address
```

and Readwritememory:

```
rwm = ReadWriteMemory()
process = rwm.get_process_by_name("ntoskrnl.exe")
```

both give me the `process not found` error! Any help on how to attach my program to the kernel level process and get it's base address would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying this too. All I could find in regards so far is this:

```
def get_base_address(driver=None):
    """ Returns base address of kernel modules """

    if platform.architecture()[0] == "64bit":
        lpImageBase = (c_ulonglong * 1024)()
        lpcbNeeded = c_longlong()
        psapi.GetDeviceDriverBaseNameA.argtypes = [c_longlong, POINTER(c_char), c_uint32]
    else:
        lpImageBase = (c_ulong * 1024)()
        lpcbNeeded = c_long()
    driver_name_size = c_long()
    driver_name_size.value = 48
    psapi.EnumDeviceDrivers(byref(lpImageBase), c_int(1024), byref(lpcbNeeded))

    for base_addr in lpImageBase:
        driver_name = c_char_p("\x00" * driver_name_size.value)
        if base_addr:
            psapi.GetDeviceDriverBaseNameA(base_addr, driver_name, driver_name_size.value)
            if driver == None and driver_name.value.lower().find("krnl") != -1:
                print("[+] Retrieving kernel info...")
                print("[+] Kernel version: {:s}".format(driver_name.value))
                print("[+] Kernel base address: {:#x}".format(base_addr))

                return (base_addr, driver_name.value)
            elif driver_name.value.lower() == driver:
                print("[+] Retrieving {:s} info...".format(driver_name))
                print("[+] {:s} base address: {:#x}".format(driver_name, base_addr))
                
                return (base_addr, driver_name.value)
    return None

get_base_address("ntoskrnl.exe")
```

I'm just happy that I'm not alone in the wild chase XD!